# Retrieve img from mysql database using PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to display a blob (which can be a jpg or a png) in PHP so i dit that:

```
$soc ='5';
$sql = "Select fpsoc, type_logo, blob_logo from plogo_s where fpsoc ='".$soc."'"; 
$q = $base->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
$q->bindColumn(1, $soc,  PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$q->bindColumn(2, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$q->bindColumn(3, $blob_logo, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

header("Content-Type: ".$type);

fpassthru($blob_logo);
```

but i have this error: " fpassthru() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given"
Where am i wrong ? 
Thx for your help :)

Edit: $type give "image/jpeg" but when i just wrote this inside the quote (without the variable) like that header("Content-Type: image/jpeg") my project display nothing and i have no error :/ just that http://puu.sh/6zVIj.png

Edit2: this is how i upload the img on the database

```
    $img_type = $_FILES['fic']['type'];
    $img_nom =  $_FILES['fic']['name'];     
    $img_blob = file_get_contents($_FILES['fic']['tmp_name']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO plogo_s (FPSOC, ID_LOGO, Blob_logo, Nom_logo, type_logo) VALUES (:soc, :id, :blob, :nom, :type) "; 
    $req = $base->prepare($sql);
    $img_blob = addslashes($img_blob);
    $soc = 'XX';
    $id= null;
    $req->bindParam(':blob',$img_blob);
    $req->bindParam(':nom', $img_nom);
    $req->bindParam(':soc', $soc);
    $req->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $req->bindParam(':type', $img_type);
    $req->execute();
```

Something wrond during upload maybe ?

Comment: `$blob_logo` is string, its not a resource , you just have to echo the $blob_logo after the header

Comment: When i do an echo to $blob_logo i get some text, binary i think, i don't really know, but not an img...

Comment: `echo $blob_logo` instead of fpassthru($blob_logo)

Comment: echo $blob_logo display that : http://puu.sh/6zVp5.png :/ not an img

Comment: what does the $type hold?

Comment: echo $type give "image/jpeg"...

Comment: this should work. what are you getting as o/p

Comment: @Nouphal.M with $type i get http://puu.sh/6zVp5.png and without i get nothing :( BUT. if i do .base64_encode("image/jpeg") i get the same that with $type. Why ?

Comment: do you encode the blob data with base 64 before saving ?

Comment: `header("Content-Type: ".base64_encode("image/jpeg"));` this works (don't show the img though ) this didn't work `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");`  :/

Comment: no i did not encode $blob_logo

Comment: is the image data any way encoded before its saved? can you just echo the `$blob_logo` and put it in `pastebin` and share the url

Comment: $blob_logo has addslashes() when i upload it on the BDD but nothing else. That's what the echo give : http://pastebin.com/b7yzGV1n

Comment: it seems to be a png file, but still it has to work.

Comment: @Nouphal.M that's weird, i try with another jpeg file, and it's still wrote png at the beginning of the echo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fpassthru() function expects a resource of a file pointer, but here you are passing the query result as string to it. instead of using the fpassthru you just have to echo out the string.

Try,

```
header("Content-Type: ".$type);
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($blob_logo));
echo $blob_logo;
exit();
```